# Can't find error in shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying to resolve my problem for 2 days but I am blocked.
I have used many techniques to trace and find my errors. I can't resole the last one.
I can't show you my app (because of info which is protected) but I could show you my log :

```
   2017-11-17T12:30:42.395529+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: RECV {"method":"update","data":{"Refresh:shiny.action":2}}   
2017-11-17T12:30:42.399510+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-enable":{"id":"resCheck1"}}}   
2017-11-17T12:30:42.400628+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-enable":{"id":"resCheck2"}}}   
2017-11-17T12:30:42.401726+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-disable":{"id":"resCheck3"}}}  
2017-11-17T12:30:42.402768+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-disable":{"id":"resCheck4"}}}  
2017-11-17T12:30:42.403806+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-disable":{"id":"resCheck5"}}}  
2017-11-17T12:30:42.404840+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-disable":{"id":"resCheck6"}}}  
2017-11-17T12:30:42.409212+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-show":{"id":"Table1"}}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:42.410277+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-show":{"id":"Table2"}}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:42.411293+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-show":{"id":"Table3"}}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:42.412261+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-show":{"id":"Table4"}}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:42.413233+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-show":{"id":"Table5"}}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:42.414218+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-show":{"id":"Table6"}}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:42.415206+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"custom":{"shinyjs-show":{"id":"Table7"}}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:42.988820+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: Warning: Specifying width/height in layout() is now deprecated. 
2017-11-17T12:30:42.990293+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: Warning in origRenderFunc() :   
2017-11-17T12:30:42.989834+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"progress":{"type":"close","message":{"id":"18d29890333552a1","style":"notification"}}}   
2017-11-17T12:30:42.988824+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: Please specify in ggplotly() or plot_ly()   
2017-11-17T12:30:42.990320+00:00 shinyapps[236114]:   Ignoring explicitly provided widget ID "10958d701"; Shiny doesn't use them    
2017-11-17T12:30:43.073852+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"recalculating":{"name":"plot2","status":"recalculating"}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:43.061909+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"recalculating":{"name":"resultatNull1","status":"recalculating"}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:43.060594+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"recalculating":{"name":"plot1","status":"recalculated"}} 
2017-11-17T12:30:43.071686+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"recalculating":{"name":"table2","status":"recalculating"}}   
2017-11-17T12:30:43.070562+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"recalculating":{"name":"resultatNull1","status":"recalculated"}} 
2017-11-17T12:30:43.072729+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"recalculating":{"name":"table2","status":"recalculated"}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:43.075189+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"progress":{"type":"open","message":{"id":"fc51ab4582ef7a14","style":"notification"}}}    
2017-11-17T12:30:43.076200+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: SEND {"progress":{"type":"update","message":{"id":"fc51ab4582ef7a14","message":"Patientez quelques instants...","style":"notification"}}}   
2017-11-17T12:30:43.152755+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with `ggplotly()`  
2017-11-17T12:30:43.152758+00:00 shinyapps[236114]: Install it with: `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`
```

When I click on the button refresh my outputs are done. But when I click after that without changing any inputs, the application is stopped.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my problem by adding this option in my global.R script before calling the libraries:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xss2048k")
```

It is linked with problem using the package "xlsx".